# Error: azurerm_app_service.ci_rg: resource repeated multiple times

Tags: azure-web-app-service, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry, terraform-template-file

I am trying to deploy 2 different Azure Apps in the same resource group.

These Azure Apps are defined as docker images stored in an Azure Container Registry (where I previously pushed those docker images).

I am not able to deploy both of them at the same time because I think there is something wrong in the way I am defining them as Terraform is expecting to find only one `azurerm_app_service`, but I am not sure how I can work around this?

When I run this command: `terraform plan -var-file test.tfvars`, then I see this message in the output:

```
Error: azurerm_app_service.ci_rg: resource repeated multiple times
```

**How do I define "2 different resources of the same type"?**

This is the content of the `main.tf` file (where I inject the variables defined in `variables.tf` with the values defined in `test.tfvars`):

```
// the resource group definition
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "ci_rg" {
  name = "${var.resource_group_name}"
  location = "${var.azure_location}"
}

// the app service plan definition
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "ci_rg" {
  name                = "${var.app_service_plan}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.name}"
  kind                = "Linux"

  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "S1"
    capacity = 2 // for both the docker containers
  }

  properties {
    reserved = true
  }
}

// the first azure app
resource "azurerm_app_service" "ci_rg" {
  name                = "${var.first_app_name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.ci_rg.id}"

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|${var.first_app_docker_image_name}"
  }

  app_settings {
      "CONF_ENV" = "${var.conf_env}"

      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"      = "${var.docker_registry_url}",
      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "${var.docker_registry_username}",
      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" = "${var.docker_registry_password}",
  }
}

// the second azure app
resource "azurerm_app_service" "ci_rg" {
  name                = "${var.second_app_name}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.ci_rg.name}"
  app_service_plan_id = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.ci_rg.id}"

  site_config {
    linux_fx_version = "DOCKER|${var.second_app_docker_image_name}"
  }

  app_settings {
      "CONF_ENV" = "${var.conf_env}"

      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_URL"      = "${var.docker_registry_url}",
      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_USERNAME" = "${var.docker_registry_username}",
      "DOCKER_REGISTRY_SERVER_PASSWORD" = "${var.docker_registry_password}",
  }
}
```

**Edit:**

I am not entirely sure about how this Terraform thing works, but I think the label `azurerm_app_service` is taken by the "syntax of Terraform". See the docs here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/app_service.html
where the title is `azurerm_app_service`. So I don't think I can change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you need to rename the second one to something else. Like this: `resource "azurerm_app_service" "ci_rg_second"`. It obviously doesnt like the fact that it has the same name.

Comment: Thanks, tried that and Terraform deployed the resources with no error, however now Azure is taking ages to make those docker containers running

Comment: that is a completely different question. I suggest you accept this answer and start a new question

Comment: I am aware of that, I was just trying to give some early feedback. I am going to wait until I see the logs from the running containers in the Azure Web Portal so I am sure this thing went through as I expected it to. Thanks

Comment: Interesting facts: there is quite a bit of volatility in the amount of time it takes to have these apps up and running, the logs in the portal don't always show up, anyway I am sending some messages to a Slack channel to monitor when the docker container comes to life and when it does specific tasks e.g. running SQL queries in a scheduled way. It seems containers die randomly, then they hang for a while in a random way (one behaves different from the other, both in random ways), and the "DB schedule" is not quite right. Anyway, these are other issues as you said. Thanks again for the answer.